# No puedo retornar un valor desde una tercera clase

Tags: java, json, get, set

Estoy aprendiendo java y selenium y necesito ayuda. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
package com.qa.task04;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class Task04 {
   static String var, stringValue, stringKey, auxUrl, auxLinktonextpage, auxHelpbutton, url, linktonextpage, helpbutton;
        
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        BufferedReader objReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\M2204060\\Desktop\\Java\\Task04\\src\\test\\java\\com\\qa\\task04\\JsonContent.json"));
        Map<?, ?> Map = gson.fromJson(objReader, Map.class);
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : Map.entrySet()) {
            stringValue = entry.getValue().toString();
            stringKey = entry.getKey().toString(); 
            for (int i = 0; i<Map.size(); i++) {
                if (null != stringKey) switch (stringKey) {
                    case "url" -> {
                        auxUrl = stringValue;
                        url = auxUrl;
                    }
                    case "linktonextpage" -> {
                        auxLinktonextpage = stringValue;
                        linktonextpage = auxLinktonextpage;
                    }
                    case "helpbutton" -> {
                        auxHelpbutton = stringValue;
                        helpbutton = auxHelpbutton;
                    }
                    default -> {
                    }
                }
        }
        }
        GetSetUtils.setHelpButton(helpbutton);
        GetSetUtils.setLinkToNextPage(linktonextpage);
        GetSetUtils.setUrl(url);
        var = GetSetUtils.getUrl();
    }
}
```

Lo que hace es leer un documento json y convertirlo en string para poder consumir sus datos. Para ello utilicé getters y setters

```
package com.qa.task04;

public class GetSetUtils extends Task04 {
    //static String url, linktonextpage, helpbutton, link;
        
    public static void setUrl(String auxUrl) { 
        url = auxUrl;
    }
    public static String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    
    public static void setLinkToNextPage(String auxLinktonextpage) { 
        linktonextpage = auxLinktonextpage;
    }
    public static String getLinkToNextPage() {
        return linktonextpage;
    }
    
    public static void setHelpButton(String auxHelpbutton) { 
        helpbutton = auxHelpbutton;
    }
    public static String getHelpButton() {
        return helpbutton;
    }
    public static void printData() {
        //System.out.println(getValue());
        //System.out.println(getKey());
        System.out.println(getUrl());
        System.out.println(getLinkToNextPage());
        System.out.println(getHelpButton());
    }
}
```

Entonces, de la clase task04 debo extraer los datos leídos del json y utilizarlos en una tercera clase.

```
package com.qa.task04;

public class AuxClass extends GetSetUtils {
    static String vara;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(vara + "a");
        GetSetUtils.getUrl();
        System.out.println(GetSetUtils.url);
    }
    public String Final() {
       
        return vara;
    } 
}
```

Pero no importa cómo haga las invocaciones, la clase AuxClass siempre me devuelve un null.

Según lo que he leído, es la mejor forma que he encontrado para hacerlo. Sé que la lectura del json funciona, así como los get y set, al menos en task04.

¿Qué es lo que debo hacer para poder utilizar los retornos en la clase AuxClass?

Comment: Una clase es un tipo, un objeto es una instancia de esa clase. Tienes la clase `Alumno` y un objeto `Juan` que es del tipo Alumno. Los miembros estáticos pertenecen a la clase y son comunes a todos los objetos,  por ejemplo puedes invocarlos sin instanciar nada, directamente desde la clase `Alumno.metodo()` y si este método  retorna 10, `juan.metodo()` también retornará 10, porque es exactamente el mismo método (referencian el mismo espacio en memoria). Tú tienes solo métodos estáticos, es decir tus objetos no tienen métodos propios (es la clase la que lo tiene).

Comment: Entonces....debes sacar el `static`

Comment: Entonces, según entiendo, la solución sería eliminar el **static** de mis elementos.

Answer (score 0):

La lógica de tus clases, está medio flojita, en principio, los métodos de la clase **GetSetUtils** deberían "vivir" en **Task04**, pasa sus setters y getters a **Task04**, para que quede así:

```
public class Task04 {

   String var, stringValue, stringKey, auxUrl, auxLinktonextpage, 
          auxHelpbutton, url, linktonextpage, helpbutton;

   void cargarDatos() throws IOException {
      // acá colocas todo lo que estaba en tu main
   }

   public void setUrl( String auxUrl ) {
      url = auxUrl;
   }

   public String getUrl() {
      return url;
   }

   // agregas los otros...

   public void printData() {
      System.out.println( stringValue );
      System.out.println( stringKey );
      System.out.println( var );
      System.out.println( auxLinkToNextPage );
      System.out.println( auxHelpbutton );
      System.out.println( auxUrl );
      System.out.println( linktonextpage );
      System.out.println( helpbutton );
   }
}
```

Como puedes ver, quite el **main**, y en su lugar creé un método **cargarDatos**, de esta forma evito declarar variables y métodos estáticos (si es que no necesito que lo sean).

La clase **GetSetUtils** quedaría así:

```
public class GetSetUtils extends Task04 {

}
```

y a **AuxClass** le realizamos unos cambios y queda así:

```
public class AuxClass extends GetSetUtils {
    String vara;
    
    public String Final() {       
        return vara;
    } 
    
    public void cambiaVara( String algo ) {       
        vara = algo;
    } 

    public void otroMetodo() {       
        System.out.println( vara + "a" );
    } 

    public void otroMetodoMas() {       
        System.out.println( url );
    }     
}
```

Para entender como funciona creamos la clase **Principal**:

```
public class Principal {

   void probar() {
      Task04 tas = new Task04();
      GetSetUtils get = new GetSetUtils();
      AuxClass aux = new AuxClass();      
      tas.cargar();      
     
      System.out.println( tas.getUrl() );
        // imprime -> http//algo
      System.out.println( get.getUrl() );
        // imprime -> null
      System.out.println( aux.getUrl() );
        // imprime -> null
        
      get.setUrl( "http//otra" );
      aux.setUrl( "http//otraMas" );
      
      System.out.println( get.getUrl() );
        // imprime -> http//otra
      System.out.println( aux.getUrl() );
        // imprime -> http//otraMas
      
      System.out.println( aux.Final() );
        // imprime -> null
        
      aux.cambiaVara( "Pepe" );
      System.out.println( aux.Final() );
        // imprime -> Pepe
      
   }
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Principal pr = new Principal();
      pr.probar();
   }
}
```

Como seguro deduces, una clase crea un objeto, si la clase hereda de otra, hereda sus métodos, no los objetos creados.
Por otro lado, aunque cree un objeto, hasta que no inicializo un atributo, siempre que le pida al objeto ese atributo, me devolverá null.
Espero haberlo explicado claramente.